Universal link not redirecting from the home page to the home page of an app as it should
If I go to the home page of my website it should trigger the "/" route in the below code. But in my case it's simply not redirecting. Please can you tell me what may be causing this? (the universal links for webpages in the "jobs" directory are working). Please note this is using iOS universal links and Go Router.
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

  runApp(MaterialApp.router(routerConfig: router));
}

final router = GoRouter(
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (_, __) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Home Screen')),
      ),
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: 'jobs/:jobTitle', // Explicitly match job titles
          builder: (_, state) => Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Jobs')),
            body: Center(child: Text('Job Title: ${state.pathParameters['jobTitle']}')),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);


try to add this to info.plist
<key>FlutterDeepLinkingEnabled</key>
<true/>

